# how to get selected checkbox using delegated jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically created a list of checkboxes inside a table:

```
$("#employeeRegister").append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class = "check" name ="chk'+i+'" value="'+this.employeeMobileNo+'$'+this.employeeEmailId+'" </td></tr>');
```

The above code runs 10 times inside a loop to generate 10 checkboxes dynamically.

I tried using this below code to see if a checkbox is checked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#smsbutton", function () {
        console.log('alert');
        $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function () {
            alert(checked);
        });
    });
});
```

`smsbutton` is a button on whose click event I want to get checkboxes that are checked.  But it does not work. What do I do to get all checked checkboxes?

Comment: Your selector is `[name=type]`, yet the `append` checkbox is `name='chk' + i`

Answer (score 0):

just use an attribute selector like

```
$(document).on("click","#smsbutton", function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

    console.log($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').serialize());
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on("click","#smsbutton", function(e){
    if (e.handled !== true) {
        e.handled = true;
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
           console.log(this.value);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: depends on no of rows in my database.

Comment: `checked').each(function()` runs as many times as the no of checkboxes there t get the value.. You will always need to loop through..

Comment: Okay now this wont print twice.. Ive edited it.. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input.check:checked").each(function() {
    alert(this.name + " is checked");
});
```